# How many ways are there to select an unordered group of eight numbers between 1 and 25 inclusive with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics

a.)How many ways are there to select an unordered group of eight numbers
between 1 and 25 inclusive with repetition?
b.)In what fraction of these ways is
the sum of these numbers even?

I'm comfortable with my answer for part a.), for which I came up with <sub>32</sub>C<sub>8</sub>.

I'm unsure about part b.) My reasoning was that to get an even sum, you'd need even numbers each of odd and even numbers being added together. With a total of 13 odd numbers and 12 even numbers, I began my solution as C(12+8-1,8) * C(13+0-1,0) + C(12+6-1,6) * C(13+2-1,2)...and iterated until reaching C(12+0-1,0) * C(13+8-1,8). This led me to my answer of

[<sub>19</sub>C<sub>8</sub>+ <sub>17</sub>C<sub>6</sub>* <sub>14</sub>C<sub>2</sub>+<sub>15</sub>C<sub>4</sub>* <sub>16</sub>C<sub>4</sub>+<sub>13</sub>C<sub>2</sub>*<sub>18</sub>C<sub>6</sub>+<sub>20</sub>C<sub>8</sub>]/<sub>32</sub>C<sub>8</sub>.

Can anyone confirm if this is right or wrong?

Comment: The approach of breaking it into cases looks reasonable.  What is the reason for your doubt?

Comment: @WillOrrick, I'm just generally slow in coming up with solutions for combinatorics problems and usually end up taking the long way around a problem. Thank you for looking it over!